# How to get other app intent in Android Oreo?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, metadata, android-8.0-oreo

Before ***Android O*** I get ***broadcast*** from ***other application***.I know that implicit broadcast receiver is ***deprecated*** in Oreo. But may I know what is the other method to receive the intent ?

In oreo if my application is in **foreground** I get the broadcast from other application. But when I killed the app then there is no broadcast.

The intents are the **metadata** information which trigger from **Google Play Music**.

I registered my broadcast on runtime.Then also I'm not getting the broadcast.

Comment: You can't listen to this implicit broadcast anymore. Read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: And some more reading regarding this: https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a

Comment: @HedShafran But there is other method.Because I already seen on other application with same feature.

Comment: Is it another application by Google? If so, the broadcast may be explicit. Or maybe the app queries the metadata when it opens, rather than receiving the broadcast in the background...